# Google Maps API -- the loc param

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

This post:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/maps/iVEFwNyrKss
showed me that there is a **loc** param...

Is there a way to use this param within the Google Map API.
Because without the parameter, the marker is not on the correct location :
without the **loc** param :
https://maps.google.be/maps?q=50.16824,5.629399
with the **loc** param :
https://maps.google.be/maps?q=loc:50.16824,5.629399

I need to be able to set a marker as it is set on the second link.

Any suggestions ?
Thanks a lot in advance.
dGo

Comment: This looks like a question about [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com), not the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...
As I was using the GeoCoder, it tried to find the closest known location and put the marker there...
By bypassing it (the GeoCoder), everything goes fine.